# Get keyframes with offset for walking animation

Tags: python, animation, drivers

I am making walking animation.
I always tweak Right foot IK animation values but I want to re-use it as Left foot IK animation. If I can do this I don't need to copy Right foot IK animation keyframes and paste it on Left foot IK controller.

My Right foot IK animation has 50 frames-long loop animation using XYZ euler rotation mode.

And I have a question. How do I write python script for drivers?
I think what I should do is like
Get right foot transformation value frame by frame and offset the keyframe value.If current Right foot IK has frame number 10 keyframe transformation value, I need to offset it and get  10+25 or 10-25 frame transformation value of Right foot IK and make Left foot IK have it.

Is it possible?

Comment: I managed to make the script by myself. it still need revising but works fine for the time being. I don't need to copy and  paste half part of animation anymore.